# How to change icon at title bar in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have created a MAT LAB GUI and i want to change the default icon at title bar to my customize icon. Kindly help regarding this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By doing so you will violate the licence agreement which can be found in 
..\MATLAB\<>\licence.txt

Comment: Wrong link? That seems to point to MathWorks website privacy policy. You're correct that the OP's request is against the license agreement.

Comment: I have removed the link, you can find it in licence.txt

Comment: The relevant parts of the license are also cited at [a similar question on the website of the mathworks](http://www.mathworks.nl/support/solutions/en/data/1-16N4J/index.html?solution=1-16N4J).

Answer (score 3):

Practicaly possible: **(But don't do it)**

let's assume that the figure handle is `hFigure`, then:

```
javaFrame    = get(hFigure,'JavaFrame');
iconFilePath = 'iconImage.jpg'; 
javaFrame.setFigureIcon(javax.swing.ImageIcon(iconFilePath));
```