# Change icon in the Matlab dialog box

Tags: matlab, icons

I know that it is possible to control the appearance of the title bar and the [title bar icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13970474/how-to-change-icon-at-title-bar-in-matlab)  of figure windows in MATLAB but it is against the [license agreement](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-16N4J/index.html?solution=1-16N4J).

My question is about a figure with a dialog box, can we change its icon [dialog box]?

Answer (score 0):

If by "dialog box" you mean something created using a command such as `msgbox`, `questdlg`, `warndlg` etc then no. These are figure windows like any other figure windows, and it's against the license agreement to modify their icon.

Comment: Yes, I meant `questdlg`. But this don't answer the question.

Comment: Why doesn't it answer the question? The answer is no, you may not modify the icon of a dialog created with `questdlg`. It is a figure window like any other.

Comment: As I said figures "can" be changed. Are you saying that dialog icons can't be changed at all or its just illegal?

Comment: I see. Yes, dialog icons *can*, but may not, be changed, in the same way as other figures (i.e., as described in an answer to the question you linked to). You'll need to get a handle to the figure window for the dialog box first - you may need to try `set(0, 'ShowHiddenHandles', 'on')` as `questdlg` sets its `HandleVisibility` to `callback`. Alternatively create your own dialog with the `dialog` command, which returns the handle to you directly.